Sorting Rows (Moving) using googleapis (Node JS)
My use-case is that I have a list of names in one column, and ranks in another column. I want to sort the rows first by their rank, then order each row alphabetically within their ranks.
I want the data moved as if I had just dragged the row manually, but I can't seem to find a way to do this.
I've tried looking up how to "sort rows" using the googleapis package, but I'm only finding ways to update the entire sheet - thus losing cell specific data history.

Please provide minimal reproducible example
